# Check word density within a document

Tags: java, algorithms

Here is the situation:
I have a `Document(d)` and a set of `keywords (Set<String> keywords)`. I like to check the density of each words from `set keywords` with `d`.
I have few solution but not really good. for example:
(NOTE the implementation is in java.)

```
Map<String,Integer> map
for each word in keywords do :
 d1 = d;
 int count=0;
 while(d1!=null) do:
    int next=firstOccurrenceOF word;
    if(next==-1){
      d1=null;
      continue;
    }
    d1=substring(firstOccurentOf word + word.length, d1.length())
    count++;
 od
 map.put(word,count);
od;
```

This solution works but its very slow if document is big and lots of keywords are needed to be checked.

NOTE: keywords set may contain keywords with multiple words

This is more algorithmic problem rather than programming.

Comment: You should iterate *once* over the document, and compare each word to each of your keywords. This means both your loop and your data structure would have to be nested the opposite way from now.

Comment: @KilianFoth well because my keyword set may contain dual/tirple and ... words then I can't really iterate through the document, for example keyword set may contain word such as : "deterministic algoirthm"

Answer (score 1):

For maximum efficiency, use your set of keywords to create a `Pattern`, e.g.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("circle|ellipse|parabola|hyperbola|conic\s*section");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(text)
while (m.find()) { ... }
```

This is about as fast as you can go in Java.

Comment: Would there be any issues or limitations related to the number of words in the expression?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner it will work fine for hundreds of words, possibly thousands.  You need to think about how you want to handle whitespace in phrases.

Comment: This is interesting, However there is problem with using regular expression. I had this problem before. for example what if the document have word such as "hyperbolatic". regular expression would still match "hyperbola", obviously use can solve that using **delimiters** (for now lets say \b).

Comment: the other problem is the complexity of regular expression. in java to find if a word **exists** in a document using string.index(...) is about 20 times faster than using the regular expression. [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674318/efficient-regular-expression-for-big-data-if-a-string-contains-a-word). Obviously Regular expression can be used, but speed is the most important thing for me.

Comment: @nafas: how have you measured this?  If searching a short string the time to compile the regular expression will dominate the search time.  Here we are concerned with the speed over a very long string, so that the time to compile the regular expression is negligible.  I am skeptical that indexOf will be much faster than the equivalent regular expression match when searching a long string.  They will do essentially the same work in the same way.

Comment: @kevincline Please check This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674318/efficient-regular-expression-for-big-data-if-a-string-contains-a-word). I explained 3 algorithms with the time taken. don't get me wrong. the efficiency of the RegEx used is extremely "relevant".  by the way I'm referring to a two pages document as "long String". Not quite sure if u were referring to a much bigger string.

Comment: @nafas: your first attempts where inefficient because of the unnecessary ".*" in the regular expressions.  What timings did you get between "indexOf" and anubhava's suggestion?  Also you didn't compare alternate solutions to the OP's problem, which is to locate and count all occurrences of several words.

Comment: @kevincline well I did mention that was the comparison to check the existence of a word. I'll gonna put both our algorithm into test in next few days and post the results.although I don't have high hopes for mine(that's y I put in here)